# How do I save Matt?

Tags: until-dawn

My understanding is that at a certain point in the story, Matt will die unless he has the flare gun to defend himself. A guidance totem told me to give it to him, which I did, and he immediately fired the flare into the air, wasting it. Reading online indicates he doesn't always fire it.

What choice did I make earlier that caused him to fire it? Is there any other way to save him without it? Is the guidance totem a dirty liar that lies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying not to give away too many spoilers here, but read at your own risk anyway:

It is still possible to save Matt even if he wastes the flare gun. In this case, you have to choose to immediately jump instead of trying to rescue Emily when she is hanging from the toppled tower.

However, if you do not want Matt to waste the flare gun, you must disagree with Emily when she says to go to the tower. In this case, Matt will not shoot the flare gun, and you can attempt to rescue Emily.

Also you must not attack the deer.

[More information here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/827528-until-dawn/72385121)

Comment: Do you know if Matt catching Emily and Mike together in the beginning or who Matt sides with when Emily and Jessica are fighting has any influence on his survival or will that only affect their relationship?

Comment: I believe those choices only affect their relationships and a few small bits of dialog a little later.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually Save Matt, and not get bitten as Emily, and still keep their relationship.

All you have to do, is give Emily the flare gun, and attempt to save Emily once, before jumping away. In this scenario, Matt still survives, Emily can use the flare gun to defend herself, and she tells the Police that he tried to save her.